# Is the inclusion into a coproduct an equalizer?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, coproduct

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with finite limits and binary coproducts. Let $1$ denote the terminal object, and let $\langle\rangle_A : A \rightarrow 1$ denote the unique map from $A$ to $1$. If we have two objects $A,B$, then we can form their coproduct $A+B$, and we have a map $\langle\rangle_A + \langle\rangle_B : A+B \rightarrow 1+1$. However, we can also map all of $A+B$ to the terminal object, and include that into $1+1$ on the left side, giving us the map $i_1 \circ \langle\rangle_{A+B} : A+B \rightarrow 1+1$. **My question is: is $i_1 : A \rightarrow A+B$ the equalizer of these two arrows?**

[image]

Intuitively, this makes sense to me. The "$A$ part" of $A+B$ is precisely what's getting sent to the left component of $1+1$ by $\langle\rangle_A+\langle\rangle_B$, so $A$ should be the equalizer. However, I don't see how it's possible to recover a map $X \rightarrow A$ from a map $X \rightarrow A+B$. This leads me to believe this is not true in general. However, I'm not familiar enough with category theory to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: Most lattices (considered as categories) provide counterexamples, because the satisfy $1+1=1$ (and also because all equalizers in a poset are isomorphisms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This need not be true.

For example, in an abelian category, $1 + 1 \simeq 1 \times 1 \simeq 1,$ so your diagram will look like $A + B \rightrightarrows 1,$ for which the equalizer is necessarily $A + B.$

Comment: I guess this works as a counter-example whenever you have a zero object, right?

Comment: @Sambo Of course, as long as some $A + B$ is not equal to  $A$.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually true in **extensive categories**. We'll use the definition given by Carboni, Lack, and Walters, in their paper *Introduction to extensive and distributive categories*. The property of extensivity that we need is found in proposition 2.2: if a category $\mathcal{C}$ (assumed to have binary coproducts) is extensive, then for any commutative diagram as below, where the bottom row is a coproduct,

[image]

the two squares are pullbacks iff the top row is a coproduct.

To see how this can be applied to the problem at hand, we consider the following diagram.

[image]

We know both rows are coproducts, and it's easy to check that the diagram commutes. Therefore, by the above extensivity property, the left square is a pullback.

It remains to show that the left square being a pullback implies the equalizer condition we want. Concretely, the pullback property states that $\forall X$, $\forall f : X \rightarrow 1, \; g : X \rightarrow A+B$ such that $i_1 \circ f = (\langle\rangle_A + \langle\rangle_B) \circ g$, there exists a unique $h : X \rightarrow A$ such that $f = \langle\rangle_A \circ h$ and $g = i_1 \circ h$.

[image]

But, because $1$ is a terminal object, this $f$ must be $\langle\rangle_X$. The equality $f = \langle\rangle_A \circ h$ automatically holds, and $i_1 \circ f = i_1 \circ \langle\rangle_X = i_1 \circ \langle\rangle_{A+B} \circ g$. Therefore, the condition can be rewritten as: $\forall X$, $\forall g : X \rightarrow A+B$ such that $(i_1 \circ \langle\rangle_{A+B}) \circ g = (\langle\rangle_A + \langle\rangle_B) \circ g$, there exists a unique $h : X \rightarrow A$ such that $g = i_1 \circ h$. This is precisely the equalizer condition.